# tipfy on Google App Engine (GAE) installing extensions

Tags: python, google-app-engine, tipfy

I'm trying to get **[tipfy](http://code.google.com/p/tipfy/)** working on **Google App Engine** (GAE). I'm using **Windows XP**.

The "hello world" example is working fine. What I'm don't understand is how to correctly install extensions.

I'm trying to use the ["multi-auth" example](http://code.google.com/p/tipfy-ext-auth/source/browse/#hg/examples/multi-auth) without much success.

I'm receiving the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named wtforms.validators
```

I've tried installing the extension, as per the [documentation](http://www.tipfy.org/wiki/guide/extensions/#adding-or-removing-extensions), which says to run:

> bootstrap.py --distribute

Which returns:

> Downloading
>   http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.14.tar.gz
>
> Extracting in d:\temp\tmp2frf61
>
> Now working in
>   d:\temp\tmp2frf61\distribute-0.6.14
>
> Building a Distribute egg in
>   d:\temp\tmpq4-j_v
>
> warning: no files found matching
>   'Makefile' under directory 'docs'
>
> warning: no files found matching
>   'indexsidebar.html' under directory
>   'docs'
>
> d:\temp\tmpq4-j_v\distribute-0.6.14-py2.5.egg
>
> install_dir d:\temp\tmpq4-j_v

I then run:

> bin/buildout

and get the following:

> While:
>     Initializing.
>   Error: Couldn't open D:\downloads\tipfy.0.6.3.build\project\bin\buildout.cfg

Because that file doesn't exist in the bin directory, which I'm assuming should have been placed there after I've ran:

> bootstrap.py --distribute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should run bin/buildout from the dir where buildout.cfg is sitting, not from the bin dir.
Do something like this

```
cd D:\downloads\tipfy.0.6.3.build\project
start bin/buildout
```

Answer (score 1):

`bootstrap` and `buildout` problems are caused by broken distribution in version 0.6.3 IMHO. It is better to use [all-in-one](http://www.tipfy.org/tipfy.build.zip) package.

Another issue is are missing `wtforms`. I got same problem like you but with `gae-auth` and I think `tipfy-ext-auth` also suffers from it. Simply speaking `tipfy-ext-auth` is updated to work with tipfy 0.7 and you are using 0.6.3.

Version 0.7 is development version and is not released to public yet. So one option is to start using 0.7 directly from [hg repository](http://code.google.com/p/tipfy/source/checkout). But be careful: 0.7 is not compatible with 0.6.3.

Another option is to just download [wtforms modules](http://code.google.com/p/tipfy/source/browse/#hg/tipfyext/wtforms) from latest version and put them under `app/lib` directory. I did this for my project and it worked.

Comment: Just one quick note because I just ran into this issue: tipfy.ext.wtforms is only a wrapper around wtforms, not wtforms itself, so the extension goes in distlib/tipfy/ext/, and wtforms goes in lib/